# Python pip install error 1

Tags: pip, setuptools

pip install works in general for various packages but when I tried to install a certain package it gave my a pycryptodome error. I noticed pycryptodome was not installed so I did pip install pycryptodome and I got

```
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\jferna~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ikwrb7\\pycryptodome\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\jferna~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-5bcrar-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jferna~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ikwrb7\pycryptodome
```

At this point I do not know what to do. I have another machine with everything working great. I do not know to to troubleshoot any further. I did pip install --upgrade setuptools already.

Comment: Have a read through the [installation documentation](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html) and see if that can help. It suggests to use `pip install pycryptodomex
`.

Comment: Same error with pycryptodomex